# How do I switch between buffers in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

I've opened a few files in Neovim which are loaded into buffers.

I'd like to be able to move between these files/buffers. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

There are various ways to achieve what you want. Pick what you like.

1. First run command `:ls` to print the buffer info. You see something like the following:

> 1 h "foo.txt" line 2
> 3 h "bar.txt" line 5

The first number in each line is the buffer number. Then run command `:buffer` followed by buffer number, e.g., `:buffer 3` will open `bar.txt`.

2. Use a plugin like [bufferline.nvim](https://github.com/akinsho/bufferline.nvim). Once installed, it can show all your opened files in the tabline. You can then click the tabline to open a certain file, just like what you have done in a GUI editor.
3. Use a fuzzy finder like [telescope.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim). Then run command `:Telescope buffers` to choose the buffer you want to open fuzzily.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am a vim, not a nvim user. But I assume the help is similarly
organised or at least gives applicable advice in this case.

I would see `:help windows.txt`, and in particular from line 618:

```
==============================================================================
7. Argument and buffer list commands            *buffer-list*

      args list               buffer list             meaning ~
1. :[N]argument [N]         11. :[N]buffer [N]      to arg/buf N
2. :[N]next [file ..]       12. :[N]bnext [N]       to Nth next arg/buf
3. :[N]Next [N]             13. :[N]bNext [N]       to Nth previous arg/buf
4. :[N]previous    [N]      14. :[N]bprevious [N]   to Nth previous arg/buf
5. :rewind / :first         15. :brewind / :bfirst  to first arg/buf
6. :last                    16. :blast              to last arg/buf
7. :all                     17. :ball               edit all args/buffers
                            18. :unhide             edit all loaded buffers
                            19. :[N]bmod [N]        to Nth modified buf
      .           .           .           .           .       
      .           .           .           .           .       
      .           .           .           .           .
```

and from line 1200 onwards:

```
:[N]b[uffer][!] [+cmd] [N]      *:b* *:bu* *:buf* *:buffer* *E86*
    Edit buffer [N] from the buffer list.  If [N] is not given,
    the current buffer remains being edited.  See |:buffer-!| for
    [!].  This will also edit a buffer that is not in the buffer
    list, without setting the 'buflisted' flag.
    Also see |+cmd|.
      .           .           .           .           .       
      .           .           .           .           .       
      .           .           .           .           .
```